# can we show change in frequency of a SIMULINK model using FFT

Tags: matlab, fft, simulink

i have a SIMULINK model. it is a PLL. now i want to see the changes in the Frequency which is the output of the PLL. So is there any way by which i can see the changes in Frequency. of the PLL. can FFT help me to show the changes in the Frequency?

Comment: I'm working in Simulink too but can't understand your question :( I Assume FFT - is a fast Fourier transformation? but what is PLL? And can you show some code or picture maybe? Or it's not necessary and  I just didn't get it?

Comment: Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see the frequency changes, then the output of the PLL can be used as an input to a, say, sine box or controlled voltage source.

Then I would use the scope box to plot the initial and final signals. Finaly,by just zooming in the waveforms you should be able to verify that your frequency has changed.

Please let me know If I got something wrong.

--Kostas